# Why can't I center a <td> in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

In Firefox, "C" is centered, due to the CSS blurb at the beginning. Why does IE7 left-justify it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="width: 300px; background-color: #888">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">C</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add something like color: #FF0000; to see if IE7 is even picking up the styling in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because you have `width: 130px;`. Try setting width only for the small cells, for example by:

```
td.span {
  width:auto;
}

<td colspan="2" class="span">C</td>
```

See example: http://jsbin.com/etoka
You can also do it the other way around - giving a class to the small cells, the whole row, or best: setting the width of the `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

always use this for position a object in center in your page 
this feature is worked in all popular browser like IE FF Safari Chrome Opera

```
<center> This is my centered text</center>
```

please give me vote if your problem is solved

Comment: `<center>` is a deprecated tag. It works but you shouldn't use it. You should use `CSS` instead.